# Is it safe to use integers as hash keys?

Tags: hashmap, integer, key, raku

Is it safe to use integers as hash keys?

```
my %hash;
my $str = ...

for $str.NFC {
    %hash{$_} = ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A normal [`Hash`](http://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash) coerces all its keys to strings:

```-perl6
my %a = '1' => 'foo', 2 => 'bar';

say %a.pairs.perl;  # ("1" => "foo", "2" => "bar").Seq
```

Note how the second key became the string `"2"`, even though it was originally passed to the Hash as an integer.
When you do hash look-ups, the subscript is also automatically converted to a string before it is used:

```-perl6
say %a{"2"}.perl;   # "bar"
say %a{2}.perl;     # "bar"
```

Note how the subscript `2` correctly found the element with key `"2"`.

The conversion from integers to strings is well-defined in Perl 6, yielding a unique string for each unique integer, so the example you gave is fine.

---

If you *don't* want your Hash keys to be converted to strings, you can override the key handling using the `{}` notation in the declaration:

```-perl6
my %b{Any} = '1' => 'foo', 2 => 'bar';

say %b.pairs.perl;  # ("1" => "foo", 2 => "bar").Seq

say %b{"1"}.perl;   # "foo"
say %b{1}.perl;     # Any

say %b{"2"}.perl;   # Any
say %b{2}.perl;     # "bar"
```

Note how in this case the second key `2` stays an integer, and doing a look-up with the string subscript `"2"` does not find it, nor does the subscript `1` find the entry with key `"1"`.

`%b{Any}` means "accept keys of any type, and don't coerce them". This is sometimes called an '[object Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash#Object_hashes_and_type_constraints)' because it can map from any object to a value.

`%b{Int}` would mean "accept only `Int` keys, and don't coerce them". In this case you'll get an error if you even try to use anything that isn't already an `Int`.